# titletoc: Partial tables of contents within subfile

Tags: table-of-contents, standalone, titletoc, subfiles

My master file is not able to call subfiles (using `input`)
which contain code to print a partial table of contents.

I run subfiles using the `standalone` package.
The subfile, when run standalone works fine.

The following line of code generates an undescriptive error message:

```
\printcontents[Scripts]{}{1}{ \subsection*{List of Contents} } \clearpage
```

I know that the `\printcontents` command gives me trouble
if the subfile has not been run standalone at least once
without the `\printcontents` command.

(Effectively, `\startcontents` and optionally `\stopcontents`
must have already generated a partial toc file for `\printcontents`
to not produce an error.)

I am wondering if the `\printcontents` command generates an error
because it cannot find the partial toc file when run from the master file.

(The master file is in a higher-level parent directory.)

If this is the problem:
**Is it possible to include a relative directory

along with the partial toc filename within the `\printcontents` command?**

### MWE

**masterFile.tex**:

```
%! arara: lmkclean
%! arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes }
%! arara: bibtex
%  arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes }
%  arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes }
%  arara: lmkclean
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\providecommand{\main}{.}
\input{\main/Subfiles/Preamble.tex}                     % Preamble [document configuration]

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Contents}      \tableofcontents   \clearpage



\input{\main/Subfiles/2-Main/child1.tex}




\textbf{\LARGE{Appendices}}
\addappheadtotoc
\begin{appendices} \clearpage


\input{\main/Subfiles/3-Append/childA.tex}


\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

**Subfiles/Preamble.tex**:

```
% meta tools
\usepackage{standalone}                 % allows for independent runs of subfiles.

% layout: page/spacing/headings
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}           % improved header commands. [supercedes `fancyhdr' package].
\usepackage{appendix}                   % appendices.

% references
\usepackage{titletoc}                   % allows sub-[tables of contents]. [breaks \section* commands. use \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} instead.]
```

**Subfiles/2-Main/child1.tex**:

```
%! arara: lmkclean
%! arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes }
%! arara: bibtex
%  arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes }
%  arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes }
%  arara: lmkclean
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\providecommand{\main}{../..}
\input{\main/Subfiles/Preamble.tex}                     % Preamble [document configuration]

\begin{document}



\section{Section 1} \clearpage

\subsection{Subsection 1.1} \clearpage

\subsection{Subsection 1.2} \clearpage

\section{Section 2} \clearpage

\subsection{Subsection 2.1} \clearpage

\subsection{Subsection 2.2} \clearpage

\end{document}
```

**Subfiles/3-Append/childA.tex**:

```
%! arara: lmkclean
%! arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes }
%! arara: bibtex
%  arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes }
%  arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes }
%  arara: lmkclean
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\providecommand{\main}{../..}
\input{\main/Subfiles/Preamble.tex}                     % Preamble [document configuration]

\begin{document}

\startcontents[appendices]


\IfFileExists{\main/Subfiles/3-Append/childA.ptc}{ 
\printcontents[appendices]{}{1}{ \subsection*{List of Contents} } \clearpage
                                                         }{}



\section{Section A} \clearpage

\subsection{Subsection A.1} \clearpage

\subsection{Subsection A.2} \clearpage

\section{Section B} \clearpage

\subsection{Subsection B.1} \clearpage

\subsection{Subsection B.2} \clearpage




\stopcontents[appendices]

\end{document}
```

.
.
.

### Digression:

Does anyone know of a method to not run `\printcontents`
if the .toc file which `printcontents` is seeking does not exist?

[Answer]: *(per @ChristianHupfer.  Give him +1 in the comments.)*

```
\IfFileExists{yourlocaltocfilename}{\printcontents....}{}
```

Comment: `\IfFileExists{yourlocaltocfilename}{\printcontents....}{}` perhaps?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Awesome. No more needing to comment, then run, then uncomment, then run.  And I'll be able to verify whether the parent file is able to see the file. [Does that require any specific package?]

Comment: No, `\IfFileExists` is a LaTeX 'core' command  (defined in `latex.ltx`) -- it's always there until someone screws it up by accident ;-) -- Don't forget the third `{}` pair, however!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Alright. So, that definitely fixes the comment, run, uncomment, run issue. Master file still errors out. Which is weird. It's like the master file searches for the .ptc file in its own folder, but it must generate the .ptc in the subfile's folder since it doesn't create one for itself.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a version of your file such that it is compilable.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer MWE provided as requested.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The question has changed slightly:  With the MWE provided, if `childA.ptc` exists, it is found by the parent and by the child, and a partial toc appears as intended.  If the `.ptc` does not exist, however, the master does not create one.

Comment: Your setup requires us to use explicitly your directory tree :-( This is tedious

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Apologies. I had assumed you wanted the other way, but the problem went away in that format. I recreated the original setup and ultimately found that it was because I loaded `hyperref` before `titletoc`. I think I read some that I should always load `hyperref` last; is that a golden rule of latex?

Comment: Yes, that's the golden rule, only to be ruled out by the platinum rule of LaTeX: Use `cleveref` after `hyperref`, if `cleveref` is needed ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer As an added note: the `.ptc` file needed to be deleted whenever commenting out / shifting around packages.  This led to a lot of false errors. I think I tried the `hyperref` solution previously; however, the problem persisted because the old `.ptc` remained, causing a similar error.

Comment: Yes I know, as well as with `babel` etc. settings ;-) All very well-known features of LaTeX ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ["features"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLlvOt09XOAhVCXR4KHaydA0YQjBwIBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fci.memecdn.com%2F505%2F504505.jpg&psig=AFQjCNHgr4kN_j6qskrl0c1ScUxaVjrHyQ&ust=1471976846960064) :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading `hyperref` before `titletoc` will cause issues.

Always load `hyperref` last.

Comment: Not always: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before :)